# IE8 - "certain" css not rendering when linking from subdirectory?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, html5boilerplate

I'm using **Paul Irish's HTML5 Boiler Plate.**

The homepage renders fine on Chrome, Firefox, and IE8 (apart from the shadows / rounded corners - which is not of concern right now)

The margins, `nav` list are messed up in IE8. 
It is linking to the CSS correctly, because the styles for the elements in the `header` come from the same file, but the positioning, and the `nav` list don't get their styles?

This is weird, because if there were issues in the CSS, wouldn't it render incorrectly in the root directory as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `script` tag you're using to load Modernizr is using a relative URL, so it will only work at your domain's root:

```
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

Replacing it with a root-relative URL should fix this.

```
<script src="/js/libs/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

Another tag has the same problem, but it's commented out, so it's not the cause of your rendering issues:

```
<!-- Uncomment if you are specifically targeting less enabled mobile browsersdo w
<link rel="stylesheet" media="handheld" href="css/handheld.css?v=2">  -->
```

Comment: Oh, how did I overlook that? Thank you!